# How to make space between elements inside div container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-container which will be dynamically filled by elements. **Container doesn't have fixed width** (I use `max-width: max-content;`) and can contain as many element as I want. The problem is that I need spacing between these elements, but don't need spacing on the left and right side between an element and the container.

Of course I can do it with `.element{margin-right: 10px}` and `.element:last-child{margin-right: none;}`, but is there a way to achieve it without pseudo-classes and JS?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  ...
  <!-- nubmer of elements changing -->
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: You could get the last element with javascript, then add a class to this element, but it's more tedious than just using the `:last-child` selector

Comment: ow yeah, I forgot to add, that I can't use JS here

Comment: Seems to **be** a solution it's just not cross browsers yet (Not working on Chrone) - `column-gap: 20px;` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap#Flex_layout

Comment: Seems to be fully or partially supported - https://caniuse.com/#search=column-gap

Comment: Isn't `justify-content: space-between` for this exact situation? if you are worried about spacing between elements then just add margin like you were doing. You could do it in one line with `:not()` there is nothing wrong with using pseudo selectors

Comment: @Huangism I don't know the width of my container so there are not spacing at all

Comment: @Yas'ka why complicate things, just use pseudo selectors, you can do `.element:not(:first-child) { margin-left: whatever }`

Comment: @Yas'ka why are you against pseudo selectors? They work very well and behave well cross-browser.

Comment: I am not against them, I just have a task to do without them)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use flex with the `column-gap` property.

Also, setting `justify-content: space-between` will ensure an even space between elements if the width of the parent container increases.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.element {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Container doesn't have fixed width (I use max-width: max-content;) and can contain as many element as I want.

You can use `inline-flex` container because *inline elements* will fit to the its contents and will stay in one row.

> I need spacing between these elements, but don't need spacing on the left and right side between an element and the container.

You can set say a `margin: 10px` on the *flex items* and then set `margin-left: 0` to the first *flex item* and `margin-right: 0` to the last *flex item* - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.element {
  margin: 10px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 5px;
}

.element:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.element:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the opposite aproach to the one that you have already suggested. Set all the elements except the first to have a margin left.

You can then use the sibling selector:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.element {
  background: yellow;
}

.element + .element {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
  <div class="element">my element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found CSS Multi-column Layout https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_multiple_columns.asp, that's probably what I was looking for.

Comment: No, multiple column layout will allow you to distribute text on multiple columns, not divs. @kukkuz answer is the way to go.