# Flexbox Responsive Layout with multiple Columns and Rows: Best practice to realize a "column-gap"?

Tags: css

The perfect solution for my task would be the property `column-gap`, but it is not yet supported for flexboxes widely.

So I need a hack to improvise the function.

Which is please the best practice to do that?

My wish is to use `justify-content: space-between;`.

That means e.g. for 4 objects in one row: 
The first object has no margin left, and the last object in the row has no margin right. And of course, there should be a minimum horizontal gap between the objects.

That means for 1 object in one row (small displays):
As well no margin left and no margin right.

I tried to use a combination of margin, padding and pseudo-classes like last-child. But the result is, that you have to reset all those rules, when the display is so small, that only one single column can be displayed.

Minimal code

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to solve the problem. Where you do have to reset many rules with a media query for a width, where only one object fits into a row.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?  a snippet that shows your issue will be helpfull but also the render expected. If the idea is to draw a grid with matching rows and columns, then you should use display:grid. flex manage rows or columns, but not both at the same time.

Comment: so I guess what you are saying is that even when the flexbox *wraps* the space between items must be consistent... maybe you can try css grids... a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518487/how-to-make-space-between-elements-inside-div-container) but *without* wrapping

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm sorry, that my question was not clear. My english is quite poor. I build a test case to explain my intention more clearly. 

About css grids: the support is not good enough on the one hand and on the other hand my flex-items have exactly the same size. So I think, there must be a solution with flexboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what you wanted, why do you specifically want to use `justify-content: space-between` though ?

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use a negative `margin-left` (let's say 1em) on the parent flex container and `margin-left: 1em` and `margin-bottom: 1em` on the flex children. The `margin-left` value of the flex children must be identical to the nevagive `margin-left` value of the flex container.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

You can set a `min-width` on the children as well if you wish.

---

Following your comment and after seeing your design I spotted some mistakes. You'll find a code snippet below that shows you the correct way to implement your design.

Couple suggestions :

- Avoid using `id`s (#) as they are too specific and difficult to override. Favor classes and attributes selectors.
- Set your box model to `box-sizing: border-box`, it makes working with margins, paddings and calculating layouts much easier (see this [article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) on box-sizing by Marie Mosley for further explanations)
- If you are using negative `margin`s on a container don't give it a background-color or border as that will break your layout (that's what happened here when you gave `#vorschau` negative margins and a background). Set the background, border, etc. on a parent container.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
}

h1, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.seite {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 70em;
    background: #FAF2D5;
}

.huelle {
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
}

.vorschau-container {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.vorschau {
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-bottom: -2em;
}

.vorschau figure {
    margin: 0 0 2em 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.vorschau img {
    max-width: 14.5em;
    border: 0.6em solid rgb(231, 231, 231);
}
```

```html
<body class="galerie" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
 <div class="seite">
  <div class="huelle">
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <div class="vorschau-container">
    <div class="vorschau flex-container">
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Aufenthalt "Süd"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Bad "2. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Doppelzimmer</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Eingangsbereich</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Aufenthalt "1. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Küche "2. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Küche "1. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Aufenthalt "2. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Bad "1. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Bad "1. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Bad "1. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Bad "1. Quer"</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Seminarwhg./Teeküche</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Seminarwhg./Lounge</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Seminarraum</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt=""></a>
      <figcaption>Seminarwhg./Zimmer</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </div>
   </div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vehicula orci vitae felis congue porta. Maecenas finibus fermentum erat. Aenean pulvinar consequat arcu, ut pulvinar diam scelerisque non. Duis dapibus, mi nec pulvinar egestas, risus justo vehicula neque, in vestibulum turpis urna nec lacus.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

If you need further explanations ask in the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the snippet.

Yes, my wish is to use justify-content: space-between

I like to have no space around the "flex-container" and - at the same time - a min-with of space (gap) between columns and rows. 

I build a test case and integrated your suggestion to use a negative margin for the flex-container.

https://borumat.de/-/html-test/galerie/

There you can see which problems still exist. I tested with firefox.

There is an unexpected margin left and bottom at the flex-container and an  collapsing margin between the flex-container and the last p element.

Comment: @ibu Hey, after checking your design I edited my answer, you'll find all the solutions to your problems in it, if you need something explained a bit more just ask ;)

Comment: Jake, thanks so much for your help :)

Your code works perfectly. Your extra container ".vorschau-container" around ".vorschau" changed the game.
I updated my own code and it worked fine as well: https://borumat.de/-/html-test/galerie/with-additional-container

About your suggestion to add "box-sizing: border". I began to read the recommended article, but I need more time to understand the consequences. When I add that declaration to my website some thinks break, e.g. the behaviour with background-images changed.

Comment: Because I do not use an extra background-color or border for ".vorschau" I can even omit the extra container ".vorschau-container".
Than the code is very slim and simple.

Comment: @ibu Glad I could help ;)